# Define a unique index in EdgeDB

Tags: indexing, unique-index, edgedb

How do you define a unique index in EdgeDB?

For simple properties you can add `constraint exclusive` which implicitly creates a unique index.

```
required property name -> str {
    constraint exclusive;
}
```

However you can't add `constraint exclusive` to an explicitly defined index. How do you mark such an index as unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `constraint exclusive on (...)` to the containing type, where `...` is an arbitrary scalar expression. To ensure the uniqueness of multiple properties, it should be a tuple `(x, y)`:

```
type User {
    property first_name -> str;
    property last_name -> str;
    constraint exclusive on ((.first_name, .last_name));
}
```

An *exclusive* constraint implicitly creates an index.

*[source](https://github.com/edgedb/edgedb/discussions/1608)*